# Function object is not subscriptable in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

So I try to pass this through Python:

```
print("Strength:",stats[0])
print("Defense:",stats[1])
print("Agility:",stats[2])
```

...and I get this in return:

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

It means that `stats` is a function instead of a sequence. Perhaps you forgot the parens on an earlier function call.