# How do I append string from row in python

Tags: python-3.x

while doing an assignment i am struck to a question that how do i make a string from row
i am having the following problem

```
def make_str_from_row(board, row_index): 

make_str_from_row([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0) 

str = "".join[(make_str_from_row[0][0])] 

print(str)
```

the answer should be 'ANTT'

but i am getting an error

> TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"".join(['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'])`

So in your example:

```
a = ([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)
str = "".join(a[0][0])
print(str)
```

From the initial question I assumed you used a tuple.

Based on your comment:

```
def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):
    return "".join(board[row_index])
```

Comment: Sir, thanks for the code but "".join is not working within a function 
I am getting an error 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try to search stackoverflow. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339213/python-function-object-is-not-subscriptable without your code I can't answer that question

Comment: def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):

make_str_from_row([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)

 str = "".join[(make_str_from_row[0][0])]
    print(str)